# pancard structure validation in javascript and php also

Tags: javascript, php

i want to do pancard validation in javascript only.

Its limited to india only.

the structure of pancard in India is as follows..
for example : AAAAA9999A

- First five characters are letters (A-Z),
- next 4 numerics (0-9),
- last character letter (A-Z)

Each deductee is uniquely identified by the PAN 
If the PAN does not follow the above structure, then the PAN will be shown invalid

The fourth character of the PAN must be one of the following, depending on the type of assessee:

- C — Company
- P — Person
- H — Hindu Undivided Family (HUF)
- F — Firm
- A — Association of Persons (AOP)
- T — AOP (Trust)
- B — Body of Individuals (BOI)
- L — Local Authority
- J — Artificial Juridical Person
- G — Govt

The fifth character of the PAN is the first character in the surname of the person to whom the PAN belongs.

so i want of check first five letters are alphabetic then follow by four letter numeric and last one is alphabetic.

so  i create javascript as follow.

```
var panVal = $('#panNumber').val);
 var regpan = /^([a-zA-Z])([0-9])([a-zA-Z])?$/;
if(regpan.test(panVal)){
   // valid pan card number
}else // invalid pan card number
```

but its not working for me.

help is more appreciated for me.

Thank in advance.

Comment: or you can simply use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/raysk-vali for validating common fields

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is a logical error in your code. Try the below code:

```
var panVal = $('#panNumber').val();
var regpan = /^([a-zA-Z]){5}([0-9]){4}([a-zA-Z]){1}?$/;

if(regpan.test(panVal)){
   // valid pan card number
} else {
   // invalid pan card number
}
```

You have to limit the characters for how many time they have to occur in the given string.

**Explanation**

> 1. **([a-zA-Z]){5}** -> Alphabets should be 5 in number.
> 2. **([0-9]){4}** -> Numbers should be 4 in number.
> 3. **([a-zA-Z]){1}** -> Alphabets should be 1 in number.

Comment: For java exact code ->>  panNumber.matches("^([a-zA-Z]){5}([0-9]){4}([a-zA-Z]){1}?$");

Comment: The only problem is on 4th index We need validation for few characters and this regex accepts every letter on 4th index

Answer (score 6):

Well, with HTML 5 you don't have to write any javascript to add validation, at least for this PAN validation, use below input tag for this,

```
<input type="text" id="pan_no" name="pan_no" placeholder="PAN No." maxlength="10" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}" title="Please enter valid PAN number. E.g. AAAAA9999A" required/>
```

Enjoy!!

Answer (score 5):

Try this code it also tells about card type as asked by @RJParikh

```js
function pan(txt)
{
 txt = txt.toUpperCase();
 var regex = /[a-zA-Z]{3}[PCHFATBLJG]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}$/;
    var pan = {C:"Company", P:"Personal", H:"Hindu Undivided Family (HUF)", F:"Firm", A:"Association of Persons (AOP)", T:"AOP (Trust)", B:"Body of Individuals (BOI)", L:"Local Authority", J:"Artificial Juridical Person", G:"Govt"};
    pan=pan[txt[3]];
 if(regex.test(txt))
 {
    if(pan!="undefined")
      alert(pan+" card detected");
    else
   alert("Unknown card");
    }
    else
   alert("Unknown card");
}
```

```html
<input id="pan">
<button onclick="pan(document.getElementById('pan').value)">search</button>
```

Hope it works well... :)

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```js
function ValidatePAN() { 
  var Obj = document.getElementById("textPanNo");
        if (Obj.value != "") {
            ObjVal = Obj.value;
            var panPat = /^([a-zA-Z]{5})(\d{4})([a-zA-Z]{1})$/;
            if (ObjVal.search(panPat) == -1) {
                alert("Invalid Pan No");
                Obj.focus();
                return false;
            }
          else
            {
              alert("Correct Pan No");
              }
        }
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" ID="textPanNo" MaxLength="10" onblur="ValidatePAN(this);">
<input type="button" value="Check" onclick="ValidatePAN();">
```

Answer (score 1):

For JavaScript you can use

```
function validatePAN(panVal){
    var regpan = /^([a-zA-Z]){5}([0-9]){4}([a-zA-Z]){1}?$/;
    if(regpan.test(panVal)){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have my working script here to validate Pan Number, I think it should help you.

```
    function validatePanNumber(panNum)
         {

           var regpan = /^([a-zA-Z]){5}([0-9]){4}([a-zA-Z]){1}?$/;

           if(regpan.test(panNum) == false)
           {

              document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Permanent Account Number is not yet valid.";

           }
           else
            {

            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "You have entered a valid Permanent Account Number !";

            }
       }
```

Now Call this function on key event of text box

```
  <input type="text" name="panNum" onkeyup="validatePanNumber(this.value);">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```js
function pan_validate(pan) {
  var regpan = /^([A-Z]){5}([0-9]){4}([A-Z]){1}?$/;
  if (regpan.test(pan) == false) {
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "PAN Number Not Valid.";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control input_capital" MaxLength="10" onkeyup="pan_validate(this.value);" placeholder="Please Enter Pan Card" name="pancard" autocomplete="off">
<b style="color:red"><span id="status"></span></b>
```

Answer (score 0):

> As per Income Tax Act, the guidelines for PAN Card are as follows:
>
> Format For Pan Card : Eg. ABCDE0123F

```
    var panVal = $('ABCDE0123F').val();

    var vali = /^([a-zA-Z]){5}([0-9]){4}([a-zA-Z]){1}?$/;
if(vali.test(panVal)){

   // valid pan card number

} else {

   // invalid pan card number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use as provided:

```
if(!empty($_POST["panNumber"]) && $_POST["panNumber"] != "" ){

    $panNumber = $_POST["panNumber"];
    if (!preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z]){5}([0-9]){4}([a-zA-Z]){1}?$/',$_POST["panNumber"])) {
        $err .= "Only 11 digit pin code are allowed which containes 5 Charactor, 4 alphabate & 1 charctor in <strong> PAN NUMBER </strong>"."<br>";
    }else{
        $panNumber = $_POST["panNumber"];
    }       
}else{
    $err .= "Please Enter your PAN CARD number"."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return ValidatePANsubmit(pancard)" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" MaxLength="50" placeholder="Full Name">
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="pancard" id="pancard" MaxLength="10" placeholder="Pan Number" onblur="ValidatePAN(this);">

 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
</html>

<script>
function ValidatePAN(pancard) {  
 

if (pancard.value != "") {
            ObjVal = pancard.value;
            ObjValLength = pancard.value.length;
            ObjVal = ObjVal.toUpperCase();
            
            var panPat = /[a-zA-Z]{3}[PCHFATBLJG]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}$/;
            var pan = {C:"Company", P:"Personal", H:"Hindu Undivided Family (HUF)", F:"Firm", A:"Association of Persons (AOP)", T:"AOP (Trust)", B:"Body of Individuals (BOI)", L:"Local Authority", J:"Artificial Juridical Person", G:"Govt"};
            pan=pan[ObjVal[3]];


            if (ObjValLength != 10) 
            {
            alert("PAN Number should be 10 digit !");
// set the value to null - if input id name = pan & form name = myform
//  document.forms['myform'].pan.value = "";
            return false;
            }
  
            if (ObjVal.search(panPat) == -1) {
                alert("Invalid Pan No.");
                pancard.focus();
                return false;
            }
            if(pan!="undefined"){
                alert(pan+" - Pan No. detected - OK");
                                }
            else
            {
                alert("Unknown Pan card No.");
                return false;
            }
                            }
                        }
</script>
  
<script>
function ValidatePANsubmit(pancard) {  

        if (pancard.value != "") {
            ObjVal = pancard.value;
            ObjValLength = pancard.value.length;
            ObjVal = ObjVal.toUpperCase();
            
            
            var ObjValmatch = ObjVal.charAt(4);
//          alert(ObjValmatch);

            nameval = document.getElementById('name').value;
            if (nameval == "")
            {
            alert("Name not Entered !");
            return false;
            }
            var namevalmatch = nameval.match(/\b\w/g) || [];
            namevalmatch = ((namevalmatch.pop() || '')).toUpperCase();
//          alert(namevalmatch);
            
            var panPat = /[a-zA-Z]{3}[PCHFATBLJG]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}$/;
            var pan = {C:"Company", P:"Personal", H:"Hindu Undivided Family (HUF)", F:"Firm", A:"Association of Persons (AOP)", T:"AOP (Trust)", B:"Body of Individuals (BOI)", L:"Local Authority", J:"Artificial Juridical Person", G:"Govt"};
            pan=pan[ObjVal[3]];


            if (ObjValLength != 10) 
            {
            alert("PAN Number should be 10 digit !");
// set the value to null - if input id name = pan & form name = myform
//  document.forms['myform'].pan.value = "";
            return false;
            }
  
            if (ObjVal.search(panPat) == -1) {
                alert("Invalid Pan No.");
                pancard.focus();
                return false;
            }
            

            if (ObjValmatch != namevalmatch) 
            {
            alert("Pan no. 5th Character -- "+ObjValmatch+" -- not match with - Name Title First Character ! -- "+namevalmatch+" --");
// set the value to null - if input id name = pan & form name = myform
//  document.forms['myform'].pan.value = "";
            return false;
            }
            
            
            
            
            if(pan!="undefined"){
//              alert(pan+" - Pan No. detected - OK");
                                }
            else
            {
                alert("Unknown Pan card No.");
                return false;
            }
                            }
            else
            {
            alert("Pan No. not Entered !");
            return false;                   // if pan no. not entered stop submit
            }
                        }
  </script>
```

Comment: Could you please explain how your answer solves the question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const regex = /[A-Z]{3}[PCHFATBLJG]{1}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}$/;
```

- 1st to 3rd Char - Capital Alphabets
- 4th Char - Alphabet from one of these `PCHFATBLJG`
- 5th Char - Capital Alphabets
- 7th to 9th - Numbers
- 10th Char - Capital Alphabets

4th Character definition

```js
const fullForm = {C:"Company", P:"Personal", H:"Hindu Undivided Family (HUF)", F:"Firm/LLP", A:"Association of Persons (AOP)", T:"AOP (Trust)", B:"Body of Individuals (BOI)", L:"Local Authority", J:"Artificial Juridical Person", G:"Govt"};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function IsValidNumaricValue(String){
    let numberRegex = /^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?([eE][+-]?\d+)?$/;
    if(numberRegex.test(String)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }  
}

function IsValidLatter(ch){
    return /^[A-Z]$/i.test(ch);
}

function IsValidPanNumber(panNumber) {
    const regex = /[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}/;   
    if (panNumber.length != 10 ) { return false; }  
    if (regex.test(panNumber) == false) { return false }
    const charArray = panNumber.split('');
    var IsValidPan = true;
    charArray.forEach((CharOrNumber, index)=>{
        if(index < 5){
            if(IsValidLatter(CharOrNumber) == false){
                IsValidPan = false;
            }
        } else if (index > 4 && index < 9){
            if(IsValidNumaricValue(CharOrNumber) == false){
                IsValidPan = false;

            }
        } else if(index == 9){
            if(IsValidLatter(CharOrNumber) == false){
                IsValidPan = false;
            }
        }
    });
    return IsValidPan;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).