# How to check valid Indian pancard using regex

Tags: regex

I try to check Indian pancard number using regex.

Indian pan card format is 5 Alpha - 4 Numeric 0001-9999 - 1 Alpha

I tried following regex `[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}`

It's broadly speaking working fine, but it's not exactly correct for the second condition -- it accepts 0000-9999, but I need from 0001 - 9999. How should I modify this regex?

Comment: Use a lookahead: `^(?!0+$)[0-9]{4}$`

Comment: Or ```^(?!0000)\d{4}$```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pancard structure validation in javascript and php also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37251151/pancard-structure-validation-in-javascript-and-php-also)

Comment: Same Q - https://stackoverflow.com/q/37251151/4050261

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to filter out the rules you don't want.

```
^(?!0+$)[0-9]{4}$
```

- `(?!0+$)` means if the rest of following text is only made of `0`s, fail the test.

See the [proof](https://regex101.com/r/GGa8US/1/)

#### Edit

If it's not just the numbers, you can remove the `^` and `$`, and insert the negative lookahead `(?!0{4})` before `[0-9]{4}`:

```
[A-Z]{5}(?!0{4})[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}
```

Comment: ++ and `(?=0*[1-9])` is another option

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by @TonyR

```
^[A-Z]{5}(?!0000)\d{4}[A-Z]{1}$
```

Comment: The `{1}` is completely redundant, `[A-Z]` alone already says match one character in the range A through Z.

Answer (score 0):

Simple check 
As it just checks position of the characters 
`([A-Z]){5}([0-9]){4}([A-Z]){1}`

More comprehensive 
Checks the 4th letter 
`[a-zA-Z]{3}[PCHFATBLJG]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}`

The fourth character of the PAN must be one of the following, depending on the type of assessee:

```
C — Company
P — Person
H — Hindu Undivided Family (HUF)
F — Firm
A — Association of Persons (AOP)
T — AOP (Trust)
B — Body of Individuals (BOI)
L — Local Authority
J — Artificial Juridical Person
G — Govt
```